# Preload and CSP in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, content-security-policy, preload, prefetch

I have a site which has some `<link rel="preload" href="...` tags on a web page, where I also want to add as strict as possible CSP headers and as part of that I want to use `default-src 'none'`

Currently Chrome supports prefetching, but it only support the CSP directive of `prefetch-src` behind a feature flag.
So I can use the feature but not configure the security around it, so with the current `default-src 'none'` all prefetch calls are blocked.

The only solution I can find is to  change `default-src 'none'` to `default-src 'self'`, but that will of course lessen security as a lot of unwanted resources could not potentially be loaded.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Please give specific scenario, sharing your current settings, expectation and challenges so to make it easier to answer and less opinionated.

Comment: Looks like `prefetch-src` [is not yet implemented by any browser](https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_content-security-policy_prefetch-src) at this time. There are bugs ticket about that in [Chrome](https://crbug.com/801561), [Safari](https://webkit.org/b/185070) and [Firefox](https://bugzil.la/1457204)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is a bug with Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801561

I am also running into this and it is quite irksome. Seems the only solution is to set `default-src 'none'` and wait for them to fix the issue. Not ideal...